# Calculating the area and overlapping area of data points in ternary plot?

Tags: python, r, geometry, ternary

The data below illustrates flower part mass proportions of iris flower. The issue that I am struggling with is calculating the area of overlap and area of the data points in ternary plot. I thought of approaching this problem using `geom_mean_ellipse` thereafter finding the confidence ellipse of sunlight exposed yes or no. Then determining the % area which each ellipse occupies within the triangular plot and thereafter determining the % area of overlap between the two ellipses. I need guidance and help with coding % area and % area overlap and potential packages I could use.

```
Sunlight Species Sepal.mass Petal.mass Pistil.mass
Yes    Iris       0.19       0.35        0.49
Yes    Iris       0.26       0.31        0.42
Yes    Iris       0.10       0.38        0.66
Yes    Iris       0.52       0.20        0.28
Yes    Iris       0.15       0.44        0.48
Yes    Iris       0.27       0.30        0.43
Yes    Iris       0.23       0.22        0.61
Yes    Iris       0.30       0.13        0.57
Yes    Iris       0.18       0.14        0.68
Yes    Iris       0.25       0.23        0.52
Yes    Iris       0.16       0.31        0.57
Yes    Iris       0.13       0.30        0.57
Yes    Iris       0.15       0.38        0.57
Yes    Iris       0.10       0.30        0.60    
Yes    Iris       0.07       0.16        0.28
Yes    Iris       0.13       0.15        0.73
Yes    Iris       0.17       0.30        1.65
Yes    Iris       0.16       0.20        0.64
Yes    Iris       0.15       0.20        0.66
Yes    Iris       0.12       0.18        0.71
Yes    Iris       0.15       0.40        0.58
No    Iris       0.16       0.15        0.69
No    Iris       0.14       0.30        0.57
No    Iris       0.39       0.22        0.40
No    Iris       0.22       0.14        0.55
No    Iris       0.24       0.10        0.65
No    Iris       0.27       0.24        0.45
No    Iris       0.28       0.18        0.54
No    Iris       0.22       0.21        0.56
No    Iris       0.18       0.18        0.65
No    Iris       0.16       0.13        0.66
No    Iris       0.23       0.22        0.66
No    Iris       0.30       0.13        0.57
No    Iris       0.18       0.14        0.68
No    Iris       0.25       0.23        0.52
No    Iris       0.16       0.31        0.57
No    Iris       0.13       0.30        0.57
No    Iris       0.15       0.38        0.57
No    Iris       0.32       0.16        0.47
No    Iris       0.31       0.20        0.49
No    Iris       0.12       0.41        0.55
No    Iris       0.23       0.41        0.37
```

Ternary plot of the above dataset of flower parts.

```
ggtern(data=dat3,aes(x=Petal.mass,y=Sepal.mass,z=Pistil.mass,color=Sunlight))+
geom_point()+geom_mean_ellipse
```

Ternary plot of flower parts:

[image]

Comment: You have functions to compute overlaps in the development version of the geometry package. See intersectn.